# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can not find fault here you help? This is my error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param() in

I do not know what was wrong

```
        <?php
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST)) 
       {

          $login    = $_POST['login'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $email    = $_POST['email'];

        if(empty($login) || empty($password) || empty($email))
        {
          die('Comeplete all text.');
        }
        elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        {
         die('Nie poprawny adres E-mail.');
        }
        else
        {   
         include_once('config.php');

         $mysqli = new mysqli('****', '******', '*****') or die ('Fatal Error: '.mysql_error());

         if($mysqli -> connect_error) 
          die('Error Connection:'.$mysqli -> connect_error.'['.$mysqli -> connect_errno.']');


         $login     = trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($login)));
         $password  = hash('sha256', trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($password))));
         $email     = trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($email)));
         $ip        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


         $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`id_user`, `login`,`password`,`email`,`added`,`ip`) VALUES('', ? , ? , ? , now(), ?)");
         $stmt = $mysqli -> bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);
         if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->execute();

          echo 'Success';
         }
        }
      }


    ?>
 </section> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, you're using `bind_param` function on MySQL and not the `$stmt` variable.

The problem is in this line:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`id_user`, `login`,`password`,`email`,`added`,`ip`) VALUES('', ? , ? , ? , now(), ?)");
 $stmt = $mysqli -> bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);
```

Instead of typing:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);
```

You should type:

```
$stmt = $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);
```

Since the `bind_param` method is only available on the `mysqli_stmt` class. and not the `mysqli`.

Checkout the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Answer (score 2):

`bind_param` is a method of `mysqli_stmt`, not `mysqli`. It should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected. And nothing has changed

```
        <?php
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST)) 
       {

          $login    = $_POST['login'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $email    = $_POST['email'];

        if(empty($login) || empty($password) || empty($email)) // Sprawdzanie czy pola formularza nie są puste
        {
          die('Wypełnij wszystkie dane.');
        }
        elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Sprawdzanie poprawności adresu Email
        {
         die('Nie poprawny adres E-mail.');
        }
        else
        {   
         include_once('config.php');

         $mysqli = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.pl', 'u162600159_reg', '******') or die ('Fatal Error: '.mysql_error());

         if($mysqli -> connect_error) 
          die('Problem z połączeniem się z bazą danych:'.$mysqli -> connect_error.'['.$mysqli -> connect_errno.']');


         $login     = trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($login)));
         $password  = hash('sha256', trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($password))));
         $email     = trim(htmlspecialchars($mysqli -> real_escape_string($email)));
         $ip        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


         $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`id_user`, `login`,`password`,`email`,`added`,`ip`) VALUES('', ? , ? , ? , now(), ?)");
         $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $email, $ip);

          echo 'Zostałeś pomyślnie zarejestrowany';
         }
        }


    ?>
 </section> 
</body>
</html>
```